# Manage Audio Streams in Multiple Chrome Tabs and Output to different Channels

Tags: google-chrome

I'm looking for a way to manage audio output streams on my open tabs in Chrome. I'm having usually up to two tabs open with audio outputs and I'd like to controll them seperately.

I have a plugin which allows me to adjust the audio level per tab.

In adition I'd like to control where the audio get is hearable. I'm using headphones and would like to set Tab1 to the left channel and Tab2 to the right channel.

Are there any plugins that allow me to do this or do I need to use two different browsers and manage the audio output globally on the OS?

Comment: Two browsers. The tabs might be controllable internally, but the app only has one output to system audio. Think of it like a simple mixing desk, many faders but only stereo out, no bus sends or inserts.